# Unable to read one file and generate one output CSV at a time in Java

Tags: java, csv

I am reading files from one folder, each folder can have various lines of records. So I am creating two arrayList here:

```
List<Address> addressList;
List<List<Address>> addressLists;
```

I am calling `readIncomingFiles` method which returns object of `List<List<Address>>`

```
// The code structure of method which reads incomingFiles 
public List<List<Address>> readIncomingFiles() {
    //some lines of code Processing data
    if (!(addressList == null || addressList.size() == 0)) {
        addressLists.add(addressList);
    }
    return  addressLists;
}
```

Now in `addressLists` I have records from all files with all records. In `main` method I have process method where first it reads my objects `addressLists` which as all records. Suppose three files are there with three record each, it will have total 9 records.

```
void process() //main method {
    this.addressLists=this.readIncomingFiles();
    List<String> outgoingFileNames = this.getOutgoingFileName();

    //Here I am creating a list for all outgoing files which will be generated and kept in destination folder.from getOutgoingFileName method
    for (String outgoingFile : outgoingFileNames) {
        if(validate file if file contains csv in output generated file name)
             then call ProcessFile
        ProcessFile()
    for (List<AddressDto> listOfAddress : this.addressLists) {
        for (AddressDto address : listOfAddress) {
            this.csvOut = new OutputCsvDataDto();   
           //Process files and Records.
           // Here OutputCsvDataDto returns data drom result generating method which writes records in OutputCsvDataDto List.
}
```

The problem is it reads all files and all records as it returns `List<List<Address>`, also the method getoutgoing file generates 3 output file one a time and returns a list. The code structure for outgoingfile method is pasted below:

```
public List<String> getOutgoingFileName {
    for (File incomingFile : incomingFileFolder.listFiles()) {
        outgoingFilenames.add("results_" + incomingFile.getName());
    }
}
```

How can I read one record at a time? If I read one record at a time, how will I process other records? I am new in Java.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you correctly, but let's sum it up:

- there's one folder with many files,
- these files contain variable count of lines,
- each line is a record of some kind (presumably post address),
- you want read all these files, process it one-by-one, by line and save output to a file, which name bases somehow on the input file

If all of the above is correct, then first let's start with the modification of the whole process, as currently you read all the files into memory and this is something you don't really want to do. What if each file takes, like 4GiB? So better approach is to process this whole thing in a manner more reassembling a "pipeline" than a "storage".

So, it goes more or less like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File incomingDir = new File(args[0]);
    File outgoingDir = new File(args[1]);
    for (File f : incomingDir.listFiles()) {
        processFile(f, outgoingDir);
    }
}

private static void processFile(File incomingFile, File outgoingDir) {
    File outgoingFile = new File(outputDir, "results-" + incomingFile.getName());
    for (String line : /* read lines from incomingFile */) {
        Address address = parseAddress(line);
        /* write address to outgoingFile */
    }
}

private static Address parseAddress(String line) {
    Address address;
    /* do parsing */
    return address;
}
```

Of course you need to adapt the code, probably use `BufferedReader` in `while` loop (instead of `for` loop in `processFile` as above), but it's more to sketch out the concept than give a "copy-paste" answer. And think how you can make this code work in parallel and if always does it make sense.